# How do I deserialize a soap response that is just one element?

Tags: c#, xml, soap, httpclient

So after I get my response I do (Where `T` in this case is `string`):

```
var theResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
using (var stringreader = new StringReader(theResult))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    var responseObj = (T)serializer.Deserialize(stringreader);
}
```

`theResult` is:

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Hello World</string>
```

When I do the `Desrialize` I get an exception. `<string xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'> was not expected.` as the inner exception and `There is an error in XML document (2, 2).` as the message.

I am trying deserialize `Hello World` to a string or deserialize to an object when I have multiple elements with a more than just a root element.  When there is a root element with more members, I think I have that figured out.

Comment: You need to remove the namespace from the result SOAP envelope. If you   wrote the service, you can add [WebService(Namespace = "")] I think!

Comment: I did not write it.

Comment: Have a look at the XmlSerializerNamespaces. I think you can pass one in as XML setting for the serializer and remove it. Failing that.. you should have a Reference type when you added the web service.. Find the response type that holds the string and you might be able to remove it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fix the issue, you need to create the serializer with the default namespace:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), "http://tempuri.org/");
var responseObj = (T)serializer.Deserialize(stringreader);
```

You can read alittle more on this in the link below:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302290.aspx

for example if your using a custome class you can define a specific classname for the XmlSerialier

```
[XmlRoot( Namespace="urn:my-namespace" )]
public class MyClass
{
    public string MyField;
}
```

You can read more on this in the link above.

Comment: That's great.  The only issue I see with this is that I am now specifying the namespace in the serializer.  Is there a way to return this into an object.  It's just a string so I don't know how to specify that my root element is also my member.

Comment: you can create your own class with the XmlRoot attribute as i wrote above [XmlRoot( Namespace="urn:my-namespace" )], in this way you specify the structure for the serialize. is this what you mean?, or you want to deserialize an object with an unknown structure ?

Answer (score 0):

Your xml is not well framed since you have an array a root level.  You must allow you xml reader to allow for fragments.

```
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AppConfig));
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filepath);
            AppConfig configData = (AppConfig)xs.Deserialize(reader);
```